# What would be the most efficient way to push updates to an Apache server without shutting down?

Tags: php, apache, updates

What would be the most efficient way to push updates to an Apache server without "shutdown" (a.k.a. redirecting everyone to a maintenance page) in a simple `LAMP` server.

One of the idea I had is to use a `.htaccess` that redirects all requests to a single `PHP` script that just wait until they can response the requests but all connexions will remain active for that time. I don't know how much consecutive connection that server could handle.

Any tips?

Thank you

Comment: I thought php header, but that would only work for the pages you put it on. I'd like to know a good solution as well ;)

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking. Are you wanting to push php script updates and redirect all users to a maintenance page while these updates are being done? And then automatically redirect again when maintenance is done?

Comment: @Mel, actually I would like to push updates to a server with very few to none downtime visible at all. Also, I would like a solution for the users that are actually using the site.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to do that without downtime - create high available schema with at least 2 replicas of every resource you have (webserver, db server, etc).

So when you need to update all - just detach one webserber and one database server from your load balancer and update them. After you have done that - attach them back and repeat the same steps with the servers that haven't been updated yet.

Comment: That is good solution. But what about session's files or databases that are constantly updated by online's users ? It's very hard to sync a database and keep em synced while I makes the codes updates.

Comment: @Cybrix: yes, you need to write your software and set up all servers so they can be interchangable.